# Colors "too warm" with P30 pictures

Tags: camera, huawei

I bought a P30 a month ago and I'm experiencing colors issues with the camera.

The colors are way too warm, if I would take a picture of a white / light yellow potatoe, I would get an intense yellow potatoe picture.

After some research on internet it seems that it was a common problem that has been fixed last year, so is there anything I can do to fix that ?

Comment: If it is fixed, maybe it's worth opening the photos on a PC to see if the color saturation is only on phone but not on actual pics

Comment: @beeshyams Good idea, didn't think about it as my color calibration does not seem to be bad, but I'll definitely give it a try !